# Torque - countries and values

Tags: carto

I have a table containing info about countries and years, such as:
* Country
* Lon/lat (point)
* Year
* Value

For example

```
| Country | Year | Value
| UK | 2002 | 344
| UK | 2003 | 200
| UK | 2004 | 199
| Denmark | 2002 | 28
| Denmark | 2003 | 4044
| Denmark | 2004 | 388
```

I want to make a nice torque so I can visualize - year by year - it with bubbles. Big values=big bubbles.

I can't find how to do it. Have you any ideas?

Comment: First of all, are you seeing points on the map when you upload your file -- is CartoDB managing to find a recognizable geometry?

Comment: Yes, no problems with the points. The problem is how to set when the bubbles should be big vs small

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated: [Carto DB: Scalable points over time using Torque in Carto DB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138742/carto-db-scalable-points-over-time-using-torque-in-carto-db)

But, basically you need:

1. Edit the torque-aggregation-function in the CartoCSS. From `count(cartodb_id)` to, for example, `avg(your_value_column_name)`
2. Then, you'll be able to use the variable `value` that will be equal to the avg of the values that lay inside the aggregation region you've selected. Don't worry about this too much because your points seem separated enough so that they doesn't collide.

Example:

```
/** torque visualization */

Map {
-torque-frame-count:16;
-torque-animation-duration:10;
-torque-time-attribute:"time";
-torque-aggregation-function:"avg(value_column_name)";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}

#torque_sizes_ex{
comp-op: lighter;
marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
marker-line-color: #FFF;
marker-line-width: 1.5;
marker-line-opacity: 1;
marker-type: ellipse;
marker-width:[value]/10 ;
marker-fill: #FF9900;
}
```

Of course, you can edit the rest of values as the frame-count, duration, etc as your convenience.